# Cannot find fatal error?

Tags: c++, random, vector, double

For a school assignment I have to create a battleship game where one random 4 length battleship (horizontal or vertical) is generated in a 8x8 gameboard. The player has 15 torpedoes to try and sink the ship. I used a 2D vector and am pretty much done with the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void generateship(vector<vector<int> >&field);
void fire(vector<vector<int> >&field);
void display(const vector<vector<int> >field);

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    vector<vector<int> >field(8);

    for (int x = 0; x < field.size(); x++)
        field[x].resize(8);
    for (int x = 0; x < field.size(); x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < field[y].size(); y++)
            field[x][y] = 0;

    generateship(field);
    fire(field);


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
void generateship(vector<vector<int> >&field)
{
    int row, col;
    int direction = rand() % 4;
    switch (direction)
    {
    case 0:     row = rand() % 5 + 3;
                col = rand() % 8;
                field[row][col] = 1;
                field[row - 1][col] = 1;
                field[row - 2][col] = 1;
                field[row - 3][col] = 1;
                break;
    case 1:     row = rand() % 8;
                col = rand() % 5;
                field[row][col] = 1;
                field[row][col + 1] = 1;
                field[row][col + 2] = 1;
                field[row][col + 3] = 1;
                break;
    case 2:     row = rand() % 5;
                col = rand() % 8;
                field[row][col] = 1;
                field[row + 1][col] = 1;
                field[row + 2][col] = 1;
                field[row + 3][col] = 1;
                break;
    case 3:     row = rand() % 8;
                col = rand() % 5 + 3;
                field[row][col] = 1;
                field[row][col - 1] = 1;
                field[row][col - 2] = 1;
                field[row][col - 3] = 1;
                break;
    }
    display(field);
}
void fire(vector<vector<int> >&field)
{
    int row, col;
    int torps = 15;
    int hitcounter = 0;
    while (hitcounter != 4 || torps != 0)
    {
        cout << torps << " torpedoes remain. Fire where? ";
        cin >> row >> col;
        switch (field[row][col])
        {
        case 0: cout << "Miss!" << endl << endl;
            field[row][col] = 2;
            break;
        case 1: cout << "Hit!" << endl << endl;
            field[row][col] = 3;
            hitcounter = hitcounter + 1;
            break;
        case 2: cout << "Missed again!" << endl << endl;
            break;
        case 3: cout << "Hit again!" << endl << endl;
            break;
        }
        torps = torps - 1;
        display(field);
    }
    if (hitcounter == 4)
        cout << "You win!";
    else if (torps == 0)
        cout << "You are out of torpedoes! Game over.";
}
void display(const vector<vector<int> >field)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        {
            switch (field[row][col])
            {
            case 0:     cout << ". ";
                break;
            case 1:     cout << ". ";
                break;
            case 2:     cout << "X ";
                break;
            case 3:     cout << "O ";
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

But when I run the code a big dialogue box comes up with saying things like "fatal error" and asks me if I want to abort or retry. In my compiler it says there is nothing wrong with the code. Am I misusing double vectors? (This is my first time implementing them).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are most probably accessing your vectors out of bounds somewere. Use the debugger to step through your code and narrow where it occurs exactly.

Comment: "Almost done" even though it doesn't even work yet? Hah! :D

Comment: `while (hitcounter != 4 || torps != 0)` Whoops

Comment: When trying to debug out-of-bounds errors, you can try replacing all usages of `vector::operator[]` by `vector::at`, as in: `field.at(row).at(col) = 2;`. The at function performs bounds checks and raises an exception if you try to read or write out of the vector bounds.

Comment: I checked my vectors and none seem out of bounds... I still don't see the cause of the error. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Also @LightnessRacesinOrbit is the while (hitcounter != 4 || torps != 0) what you think the cause of the error is? Right now I can't see fault in it.

Comment: @e7kim: Doubtful but it looks wrong anyway. You didn't mean `&&`?

Comment: Yes I got it a moment ago that was my problem ! Thanks for taking your time to help !!!

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1 (root cause):**

In your initialisation your inner loop uses the wrong size.  ***Edit:*** When y reaches 8, you hence try to access field[8] in the condition of the loop,  and there you're out of bounds :

```
for (int x = 0; x < field.size(); x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < field[x].size(); y++)  // not field[y] !!
        field[x][y] = 0;
```

Note that you could simplify your initialisation by trading your 3 for loops against the following initialization: :

```
vector<vector<int> >field(8, vector<int>(8,0) );
```

**Problem 2 (high risk):**

Then in `fire()` you ask for `row` and `col` from user:

```
   cin >> row >> col;
```

But you don't check that the input is invalid.  If the user inadvertantly uses range 1..8 insead of 0..7 you'll go out of range.